# How to find visibility of a polygon from a vertex v in a concave polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I'm working on an assignment 2d art gallery problem to find a minimum number of vertex guards. As part of solving the problem using genetic algorithms, I would need to find out the area of the polygon that is visible for a guard placed on a vertex.

The input is a polygon with known 2d (x,y) coordinates. Could you please help me know how to calculate the visibility of the guard(i.e what part of the polygon he could possibly see) placed on a vertex of the polygon?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you narrow down your problem? The general problem you describe is quite well researched and documented. Start by creating rays from your guard through concave corners, find their intersections with the polygon, and connect them in a reasonable way.

Comment: I had this idea of triangulating the polygon. If the triangles formed have a vertex shared with the guard vertex then I can say the guard can view this triangle. If there is no shared vertex I would draw line segments from the guard vertex to every other triangle vertex and if any of these line segments cut the sides of the polygon I would consider that triangle is not completely visible from the guard vertex.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if this is an elegant solution. In terms of the general problem, I have looked at various research papers but none of them talked about the details on how to calculate the visibility. Please do share resources if you think it would be helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for finding visible area from an arbitrary point inside the polygon. You can change it to restrict point to polygon vertices:
[image]

**Step 1:** Draw rays from guard toward each vertex and find intersection points with all edges of polygon.

**Step 2:** Check if ray crosses polygon (yellow) or just touches it (purple).

**Step 3:** Sort intersections on a ray by their distances from the guard and find closet cross point. Call all further points invisible (red) and closer ones visible (green).

**Step 4:** Now each edge of polygon is equivalent to one or multiple segments, each segment that its both end points are labeled as visible will be visible. Sum length of such segments.

Here is a more complicated sample:

[image]

And keep in mind that it is just a start and you can optimize it. Think about Niko's comment for first improvement.